# how to manage very large amount of data in folders

Tags: filesystems

i have more than 25000 people data how can i manage this data so that there is no performance issue

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep it in files (and not in a DB), one important thing would be to spread them into subfolders. 25000+ files in a single folder will be *much* slower to access than 250 subfolders containing 100 files on the average.

Comment: Depends on filesystem and particular usage scenarios. My measurements on NTFS have shown that NTFS works with ~400K files faster than with the same files spread across 676 subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

More info needed.

What performance issues are you concerned about? Storage space? Lookup speed? Write speed?

How is the data arranged?

Generally such a data set would be naturally stored in a DB - is there a specific reason why you're looking at storing it in folders? Folders will egenrally require you to decide on a specific lookup system/key, wheras a DB allows you to dice the data however you wish.

Answer (score 0):

For input/output, make sure the readers and writers are buffered.